# Can anyone please help me solve the issues regarding DPARSF?

Tags: matlab, image-preprocessing, mri

I am currently doing an internship on fMRI analysis. The first step is preprocessing of fMRI data using DPABI. But I am facing this error while executing the DPARSF 5.2:
The first is when I am trying to set the nuisance regressors:
[error while clicking the Nuisance Regressors button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnQ5W.png)

Next:
After clicking on the "Run" button, the following error is showing:
[Error while clicking on the run button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhoos.png)

Note: I have not changed any code by myself. Whatever DPABI code I got from this link, I just downloaded it and ran it on a short ADNI Data. The link from where I downloaded DPABI: http://www.rfmri.org/DPARSF

It will be a grateful moment if anyone helps me out with this matter. Thank You in advance.